# Filter option in Semi-Automatic classification Plugin, QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins, sentinel-2

I usually download Sentinel-2 scenes using SCP plugin in QGIS, but I don't know how to use the Filter option in this process.

Comment: Filter by what criteria?

Comment: This is my question, what is the criteria that I have to write there? Because I have already writen some criteria like the zone or the identifier but nothing is happened. So I don't know what I have to specify there to do an advanced search.